# How to fix a missing NuGet package error?

Tags: git, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a C++ console application in Visual Studio under Git, in which I have a submodule static library called `LibrarySubmoduleSolution`. This `LibrarySubmoduleSolution` uses Windows Implementation Library NuGet package.

After I download Git submodule in my `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution` main solution and restore NuGet packages in the solution, I get these errors:

> Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line
> Suppression State Error        This project references NuGet
> package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package
> Restore to download them.  For more information, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is
> ..\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets.    LibrarySubmoduleSolution
> D:\Projects\Tests\VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution\LibrarySubmoduleSolution\LibrarySubmoduleSolution\LibrarySubmoduleSolution.vcxproj
> 166     Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line
> Suppression State Error    C1083    Cannot open include file:
> 'wil/resource.h': No such file or directory
> VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution
> D:\Projects\Tests\VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution\LibrarySubmoduleSolution\LibrarySubmoduleSolution\SomeClass.h
> 3
> [image]

I searched for answers on Google and here on Stackoverflow and even after I edit my `LibrarySubmoduleSolution.vcxproj` file and change packages folder from `..\packages` to `$(SolutionDir)\packages`:

```
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
    <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets')" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

I still can't build with the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'wil/resource.h': No such file
> or
> directory VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution  D:\Projects\Tests\VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution\LibrarySubmoduleSolution\LibrarySubmoduleSolution\SomeClass.h  3
> [image]

Only after I install Windows Implementation Library NuGet package in my main console application project, it starts to build without errors.

Here is main and submodule solutions to quickly reproduce errors:
https://github.com/KulaGGin/VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution
https://github.com/KulaGGin/LibrarySubmoduleSolution

Comment: I think your nuget package has broken and there is a problem with your project referencing the Nuget package. First, close vs instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, then restart your project, run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`--> `Package Manager Console`. The the error will disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to fix a missing NuGet package error?

I downloaded your project from the github and faced the same issue as you described.

The main issue is that your nuget packages has broken or there is a problem with your project referencing the Nuget package.

Please follow these steps and I solved the issue through them.

**Suggestion**

**1)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\.nuget\packages`

**2)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder and any output folder like `x64` folder

**3)** run the command `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**--> **Package Manager Console** to reinstall that package in your project.

**Then**, the error will disappear. I follow these and finally get it.

**Update 1**

===========================

Sorry for not observing your issue in detail. The problem is in the `xxx.vcxproj` file.

The problem is under:

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets'))" />

 <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets')" />
```

I wonder why you want to use `$(SolutionDir)` instead of `..`.

**In your issue**, `$(SolutionDir)\packages` means `xxx(SolutionName)\\packages`.

`$(SolutonDir)` means `xxxx\LibrarySubmoduleSolution\` and it already contains `\`.

**Solution**

Please delete `\` between `$(SolutionDir)` and `packages` and change to this:

`$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.targets` in both of the xml nodes.

==============================

**Update 2**

**Besides**, if your main project `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution` references `LibrarySubmoduleSolution` and uses its file, you should also include such library path in the main project, otherwise, it will not find the `resource.h` in the main project `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution`.

**Actually**, when you reference the `someclass.h` from `LibrarySubmoduleSolution` in the main project `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution`, the `someclass.h` file will be copied into `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution`, in such environment, there is no such library `wil/resource.h` while you installed it in `LibrarySubmoduleSolution`. In the main project, it did not install that nuget package(to include the include path where exists `resource.h` automatically), so the error will occur.

**As a suggestion**,

you could right-click on `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution` properties--> `VC++ Dirctories`--> add `xxxx\VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\include` into `Include Directories`.

**Or** install that nuget package in the main project to include the library path automatically.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I followed the steps exactly but I still get the error about a missing package after I do them. I recorded a short video showing how I followed them so we're sure that there's no mistake I made while following the steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWaqo6EoEiw . Note: hidden folders show up when they're there. .vs hidden folder isn't there on the video because I just cloned the repository.

Comment: Please modify your `xxx.vcxproj` file and change to use `$(SolutionDir)packages`. Delete \ between them.

Comment: `I wonder why you want to use $(SolutionDir) instead of ..`
I don't want to use `$(SolutionDir)`, that's just how I tried to fix the problem with missing NuGet package. When I don't use `$(SolutionDir)` at all and follow first 3 steps in your answer, I still get the error(if I don't install the NuGet package in the startup project): https://i.imgur.com/fZ5JTDE.png

Comment: The same happens when I change `..\packages` to `$(SolutionDir)packages`: https://i.imgur.com/Xgwjp3Q.png . I build solution with the loaded submodule project, I unloaded the project to show the `.vcxproj` file.

Comment: I just tried it even without the submodule(just created library project in the solution), and I still get this `No such file or directory` error. If I use a library project(which uses NuGet package) in my main startup project, do I also need to install that NuGet package in my main startup project? After I install wil in the `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution` project, error goes away in both cases: while just using library project and when using the submodule version.

Comment: You are right. Actually, when you reference the `someclass.h` from `LibrarySubmoduleSolution`  in the main project `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution`, the `someclass.h`  file will be copied into `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution`, in such environment, there is no such library `wil/resource.h` while you installed it in `LibrarySubmoduleSolution`. In the main project, it did not install that nuget package(to include the include path where exists `resource.h` automatically).

Comment: So for your main project, to let the `someclass.h` uses `resource.h` file, you should config the project to include the path in the main project. Right-click on `VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution` properties-->VC++ Directories--> add `xxxx\VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution\VCPPConsoleApplicationSolution\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.200519.2\include` into `Include Directories`. Or just install that package on the main project.

Comment: I have updated my answer and you can check on Update 2. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and helping me. I just thought I don't have to reference wil in my main project because it doesn't really use it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Visual Studio can go silently brain dead and keep a lock on a project or tool, that can prevent the 'automatic' restore from happening.

In these cases, it's best to:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Do a full clean of the project / solution
3. Check Task Manager for any errant processes from VS (i.e testhost.exe)
   that may still be running and kill them.
4. Restart Visual Studio and load your project and try again

Hopefully, then, automatic package restore should happen.